# Is it possible to retrieve the Role ARN from AWS account and reference it using a variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When launching spot fleet using terraform [example here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html) I need to provide this required value.

```
iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
```

Is it possible for me to retrieve the Role ARN from AWS account so that I can provide it as a variable in terraform? Or somehow reference the proper Role ARN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_role.html

This gives the role arn value if the role name is passed, for example:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "spot-fleet"
}
```